# I get TwitterConnectionError when I repeat requests

Tags: python, api, twitter, webapi, twitterapi-python

The following code, using Twitter API, repeats getting tweets while it gets 'next_token'. This results in an error, but I don't know what the error indicates. I would like to know how I should modify the code.

Here's my code

```
from TwitterAPI import TwitterAPI, TwitterPager
import csv
import pandas as pd
import time

#create a dataframe to store tweets
df = pd.DataFrame()

api = TwitterAPI(consumer_key,
                 consumer_secret,
                 auth_type='oAuth2',
                api_version='2')

#the first query without next_token
q = {'query':'(#abc -RT lang:en)', 
        'start_time': "2017-10-16T00:00:00Z",
        'end_time': "2018-03-31T23:59:59Z", 'tweet.fields':'created_at',  'max_results': '500'}

r = api.request('tweets/search/all', q)
response_data = r.json()
df_a = pd.DataFrame(response_data['data'])
#Add tweets to dataframe
df = pd.concat([df, df_a])

#Loop this process while there's 'next_token'
while  'next_token' in response_data["meta"]:
    #sleep not to exceed rate limit
    time.sleep(4)
    token = response_data["meta"]['next_token']
    #query with 'next_token'
    q = {'query':'(#abc -RT lang:en)', 
        'start_time': "2017-10-16T00:00:00Z",
        'end_time': "2018-03-31T23:59:59Z",
        'tweet.fields':'created_at',  
        'max_results': '500',
        'next_token': token}

    r = api.request('tweets/search/all', q)
    if r.status_code == 200:
        response_data = r.json()
        df_a = pd.DataFrame(response_data['data'])
        df = pd.concat([df, df_a])
    else:
        print("ERROR: %d" % res.status_code)
```

I got an error as below.

```
TwitterConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.twitter.com', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=5)
```

Comment: Are you behind a proxy server?

Comment: I don't think I'm using a proxy server. Should I use it? I'm not really familiar with this.

Comment: The question is, is your computer behind a proxy proxy server? If it is, you will need to find out it's name in order to bypass it.